# In jsonschema, how do you use the value of a property in one object to check a specific property in another object

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I would like to check the following structure:

```
foo = {
          "things": {
              "bar": {
                  "thing-definition-key": "baz",
                  ...
              }
          },
          "thing-definitions": {
              "baz": {
                  "blah": "blah"
              }
          }
      }
```

In addition to checking some schema constraints on `bar` and `baz` to make sure they're well-formed, I want to use the fact that the value of the `thing-definition-key` in bar is `"baz"` to confirm that there is an entry for `baz` in the thing-definitions object, and that it meets certain constraints. I know how to use property dependencies within an object, but not between two objects.

Note, I'm doing this with https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, but I'm looking for a language-independent answer if possible.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.